# Impossible snap button animation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, shape-keys

I'm having trouble with a project. I need to animate this play mat wich have snap button in each corner.
But I don't know how to do this. Would an cloth sim be the quickest solution? Or do you think I have to do it manually with shape key?

[image: playmat]

[image: snap button]

Thanks for help

Comment: Could always use hooks on the points, then turn it into a shapekey to animate easier.